# PHP Header Redirect Working Despite Previous Earlier HTML and echo Output?

Tags: php, html, redirect, http-headers, echo

Does anyone know why this script succeeds for me on each server I've tried?  I am successfully redirected to Google despite earlier output before the header call.

According to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), it is stated that adding headers after output fails and returns a warning.  However, I am seeing inconsistent behavior on my web servers.  I've been using similar approaches to accomplish some things, and it has worked just fine except for one case where it randomly stopped working.

```
<?php
    echo "lol"; 
?>
<html>
<?php
    header("Location: http://www.google.com");
    exit();
?>
```

So, what's the deal?  Do recent versions of PHP now allow this?

My php version is PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 on Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Comment: Most probably PHP does some caching (output buffer), thats why sometimes it works ;)

Comment: It would be nice if PHP held off on all output by default so that you could inject headers whenever you wanted.  I'd like to know the real reason though.

Comment: If you want to "hold off" the output, there are funtions for that: http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php. On the other hand, concurrent output is very important for many usecases...

Comment: Thanks, but that requires me to do more work :(.  Why isn't PHP consistent with its documentation?  The fact the above script works is not very reassuring.

Comment: Where in PHP documentation it says header() WILL fail and return warning if used after some character has been sent to output ? EDIT: Oh i see in the example on header().. well yeah i guess that is a bit unfortunate...

Comment: You're right, the documentation doesn't say it will return a warning.  So, when will I get the warning message of "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by"?  It seems like most of the time I wont, but when I do, I can't figure out why because the script above works....

Comment: Well it depends on your server's configuration. If you have output buffering turned on by default, your code shouldn't return an error. So in that sense, the documentation i not wrong. See: http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering

Comment: @MathieudeLorimier, you're right.  I do have it turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Output_buffering was enabled on my server which allows for some of this as explained by the setting:

```
; Output buffering is a mechanism for controlling how much output data
; (excluding headers and cookies) PHP should keep internally before pushing that
; data to the client. If your application's output exceeds this setting, PHP
; will send that data in chunks of roughly the size you specify.
; Turning on this setting and managing its maximum buffer size can yield some
; interesting side-effects depending on your application and web server.
; You may be able to send headers and cookies after you've already sent output
; through print or echo. You also may see performance benefits if your server is
; emitting less packets due to buffered output versus PHP streaming the output
; as it gets it. On production servers, 4096 bytes is a good setting for performance
; reasons.
; Note: Output buffering can also be controlled via Output Buffering Control
;   functions.
; Possible Values:
;   On = Enabled and buffer is unlimited. (Use with caution)
;   Off = Disabled
;   Integer = Enables the buffer and sets its maximum size in bytes.
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to Off for the CLI SAPI
; Default Value: Off
; Development Value: 4096
; Production Value: 4096
; http://php.net/output-buffering
output_buffering = 4096
```

Ugh, php.

Comment: One nice side-effect is, enabling output_buffering makes the script faster, at least on my server with 7.0.4, lol.